# Draw arrow in polyline with google maps V2

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2

I use google maps android V2 and polyline to draw a route between pointA and pointB. The problem is I don't know how I can indicate the direction. It isn't the same going from pointA to pointB that pointB to pointA.

How can I indicate the direction? Can I draw arrows in the polylines??

Any ideas?

thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot currently draw polylines with arrows. You may want to star this feature request: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4884

As a workaround for now I can suggest adding two disting objects in pointA and pointB (for example markers with different icons), that clearly show which point is start and which is end.